# Slow bootup thunderbolt IO_PAGE_FAULT

Tags: boot, thunderbolt

Recently did my first pc build and installed ubuntu 20.04 lts. Already upgraded to latest kernel.
From the very beginning it takes about 90 seconds to get to login screen which with fairly new hardware is quite long. It looks like thunderbolt issues but frankly i'm totally new to ubuntu.
[boot.log](https://pastebin.com/JTdVtr6d)
[lspci](https://pastebin.com/mEPVeUTR)
Please let me know if anything else is neccessary. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ?  I think I may have the same problem, see: [my post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365860/boot-error-io-page-fault-on-asus-motherboard-with-thunderbolt-4).

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. Yup, yours looks exactly the same. For now I simply disabled thunderbolt support in bios since I don't benefit from it yet... It makes boot up super fast but obviously is a temporary "solution"

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04 and the ASUS ProArt B550-Creator motherboard. I am using dual boot with Windows. I had to completely disable thunderbolt in the BIOS to start Ubuntu in a reasonable amount of time. However, this also disabled it in Windows :( Does anyone have a better solution?